# flot.navigate drag start/end events missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

im looking for some javascript events that trigger at the start and at the end navigating via dragging on flot plots so that i can do some ajax updates, however, I've been looking around online for some code to help me. I've found a few things, most didn't work worked or had bugs.

The best thing I've found so far is an answer from DNS, however it has unintentional behavior, when you hold the mouse click button down and stop panning the event triggers.

```
var delay = null;
element.on("plotpan", function() {
    if (delay) clearTimeout(delay);
        delay = setTimeout(function() {
        // do your stuff here
        delay = null;
    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The navigate plugin should really pass the event on to you; then you could easily check the state of the mouse buttons in your handler.

Since it doesn't, you'll need to attach your own mousedown/mouseup listeners to the overlay canvas; the child of your plot placeholder with class 'flot-overlay'.  You can use these to update a shared variable with the state of the left button, then check that value in your handler above.